# Why angular.extend is used as an input parameter to javascript push function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recently found the following code on the Ionic codePen:

```
  $scope.add = function() {
    var nextMessage = messageOptions[messageIter++ % messageOptions.length];  // some string
    $scope.messages.push(angular.extend({}, nextMessage));
}
```

Why did the developer used angular.extend({}, nextMessage) as an input parameter of to javascript push function instead of directly passing the nextMessage as an argument?

Comment: Why do not you read documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend. Here you will get exact answer

Comment: I understand that the angular.extend extend the destination by copying properties of src. My main question is why it was required to create a copy in the above code? Why can't just directly pass the nextMessage as an argument?

Comment: angular.extend({}, nextMessage) this line of code, would be useful if you are updating the current object properties with new object with same reference. But in case of array $scope.message.push(nextMessage) should work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used to create a copy `nextMessage` object and push that copy to the array.

[angular.extend()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

> Extends the destination object dst by copying own enumerable
>   properties from the src object(s) to dst. You can specify multiple src
>   objects. If you want to preserve original objects, you can do so by
>   passing an empty object as the target: var object = angular.extend({},
>   object1, object2).

Comment: I understand that the angular.extend extend the destination by copying properties of src. My main question is why it was required to create a copy in the above code? Why can't just directly pass the nextMessage as an argument?

Comment: @DeepArora it might be because... when somebody manipulates the object in the array because of logical reasons the original object may not be modified

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's Array.push() method will push items, not extend arrays.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = ['a', 'b'];
array1.push.apply(array1, array2);
console.log(foo); // will output [1, 2, 3, 4, "a", "b"]
```

angular.extend() method will extend arrays/objects, not push items.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = ['a', 'b'];
angular.extend(array1, array2);
console.log(foo); // will output ["a", "b", 3, 4]
```